# Is there a simple way to display mysql data in Django template without creating an app?

Tags: python, mysql, django, templates

I have a table in my MySQL database named mysite_categories, there are 4 columns but for my purposes I just need two (name, base_url).

I currently have a template '*base_categories.html*' that I use to load the categories manually.

**base_categories.html (trimmed down)**

```
{% block content %}
  <div class="section" style="float: right;">
    <h4 class="gradient">Category List</h4>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/categories/Art" id="nav_font">Art</a></li>
      <li><a href="/categories/Biography" id="nav_font">Biography</a></li>
      <li><a href="/categories/Science" id="nav_font">Science</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

What I'd like to do is pull the data from the db and use it in a for loop. Something like:

```
{% block content %}
  <div class="section" style="float: right;">
    <h4 class="gradient">Category List</h4>
    <ul>
      {% for category in mysite_categories %}
        <li><a href="{{ category.base_url }}" id="nav_font">{{ category.name }}</a></li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

This is probably a newbie question but is it possible to something like this without creating an app?

**`*EDIT 1*`**

These are my app files, I'll admit this is probably junk, I have tried so many edits from so many different posts I'm sure I've broke it somewhere :P. I was going to remove it and start fresh but I figure I might as well post it to see where I might have gone wrong?

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from categories.models import categoryList


def index(request):
    categories = categoryList.objects.all()
    extra_context = {"categories": categories}

    return render_to_response("myapp/index.html", extra_context)
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models


class categoryList(models.Model):
    #id = models.IntegerField(unique=True, db_column='ID') # Field name made lowercase.
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255L, unique=True)
    base_url = models.CharField(max_length=255L, unique=True)
    thumb = models.CharField(max_length=1L, unique=True, blank=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'mysite_categories'
```

**index.html**

```
{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}

<div class="section" style="float: right;">
  <h4 class="gradient">Category List</h4>
  <ul>
    {% for category in categories %}
      <li><a href="" id="nav_font">{{ category.title }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</div>
```

As mentioned, it's probably junk at this point, if any of you can help me straighten this out it would be appreciated!

**`*EDIT 2*`**

**base_right_panel.html**

```
{% block content %}
  <div style="float: right;">
    <div id="base_categories" style="margin: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px;">
      {% block base_categories %}
        {% include "base_categories.html" %}
      {% endblock %}
    </div>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

**`*Edit 3*`**

**base_categories.html**

```
{% block content %}
  <div class="section" style="float: right;">
    <h4 class="gradient">Category List</h4>
    <ul>
      {% if categories %}
        {% for category in categories %}
          <li><a href="" id="nav_font">{{ category.title }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
      {% else %}
        <p>no data! {{ categories|length }}</p>
      {% endif %}
    </ul>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

**`*EDIT 4*`**

(Application name was changed to CategoryList)

**CategoryList/views.py**

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from CategoryList.models import CategorylistCategorylist #<-- Changed to match inspectdb result

class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name="categorylist.html" #<-- Changed name from index.html for clarity

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["categories"] = CategorylistCategorylist.objects.all()
        return context
```

**CategoryList/models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class CategorylistCategorylist(models.Model): #<-- Changed to match inspectdb
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255L, unique=True)
    base_url = models.CharField(max_length=255L, unique=True)
    thumb = models.ImageField(upload_to="dummy", blank=True) #<-- Ignored inspectdb's suggestion for CharField

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    # Re-added Meta to match inspectdb
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'categorylist_categorylist'
```

**CategoryList/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from CategoryList import views

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='categorylist'),
)

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
        {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
    url(r'', include('django.contrib.staticfiles.urls')),
) + urlpatterns
```

**MySite/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from home import views as home_view
from CategoryList import views as index_view

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', home_view.HomeView.as_view(), name="home"),

    url(r'^categories/$', index_view.IndexView.as_view(), name='categorylist'),#include('CategoryList.urls')),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    #url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
)

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
        {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
    url(r'', include('django.contrib.staticfiles.urls')),
) + urlpatterns
```

So far I can load the url "*localhost:8000/categories*" and I will see the list of category names appear on the right side of the screen as expected, but there is no template formatting applied. Inside my "*base_right_panel.html*" file I've tried "*{% include "categorylist.html %}*" to link directly to the application, which displays the correct template formatting, but displays the "*{% else %}*" response from "*{% if categories %}*" instead of the categories? I have tried changing the include to point to "*categories/*", which works in the browser, but it tells me it cannot find the template?

I'm sooo stumped right now..?

Comment: If an app is absolutely needed, how would I call the results of the app and use the results in 'base_categories.html'?

Comment: Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17794168/how-to-embed-the-results-of-my-django-app-inside-a-template-using-something-like for images of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could [execute custom SQL directly](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly) to fetch categories in your view, and loop through the output in your template. This would not require an app.

If you create a model, you will be able to use the Django queryset api, which is very convenient, e.g.

```
mysite_categories = Category.objects.all()
```

This does require you to create an app. However, creating an app is really easy, just use the [startapp](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/django-admin/#startapp-appname-destination) command.

```
python manage.py startapp myapp
```

Once you've created your app, you can use the [`inspectdb`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/django-admin/#inspectdb) command to inspect your database, and create a model for your `mysite_categories` table.

Comment: I have created an app and used inspectdb to create the model. What I can't figure out is how to embed the app within the the base_categories.html? I am very new to django (and web programming in general), the purpose of this view is to have it as part of my navigation panel on the right side 'base_right_panel.html' and I use {% include base_categories.html" %} inside a block to add the category section to the right panel. Is there a way to use the app inside the "base_right_panel.html"? Can I just set the include path to the app's "index.html" file, or something similar?

Comment: What view are you using to render your template?  The view is where you do things like collect the categories and put them into the context that your template will use when rendering.

Comment: First, get the categories working in one view by including `mysite_categories = MyModel.objects.all()` in your template context. Then, if you want to include the categories on every page, you need to explore [template context processors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext) or [custom template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/custom-template-tags/) tags.

Comment: Maybe you could also clarify something for me? I was under the impression that view.py and models.py were files generated when you use startapp, how would one use these files if there is no app? can they be added to projects as well as apps? (yeah, I'm that new lol, and the tutorials out there have been pretty vague so far)

Comment: To create models, you **must** create an app with a `models.py` module, and add the app to your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting. You can create a `views.py` in your project root if you wish, and import its views in your project's root `urls.py`.

Comment: @Alasdair Please see the above edit for my (probably broken) app code. I have already added the app the INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: It looks ok. Two small improvements would be to use the `render` shortcut instead of `render_to_response`, and name the model `CategoryList` instead of `categoryList`, but those things won't stop it from working. I'm not sure why you've commented out the id field either. You need to update your question to say what error you are getting, or what is not working.

Comment: The id field was causing an error about assigning the primary key, which I'm sure I can resolve but I don't really have a use for it in the long run. With regards to the specific error, I can't really say because I cannot figure out how to initiate the app inside a block within "base_right_panel.html" to see if it works or not?

Comment: @PeterDeGLopper Please see the above edit for the views.py code

Comment: "Initiating an app inside a block" doesn't really make sense. First, hook up your index view to a URL, include the category code in its template, and make sure you can display the categories as you want. Then, to display the categories on multiple pages, explore context processors and template tags as I suggested before. Good luck!

Comment: I do not know what you mean by 'initiate the app'.  Once your view code has provided the necessary context, it is available to the template engine without further work.  Templates are tools a view can use to create a response - some of your comments seem to me to be assuming a greater importance to templates than they actually have.

Comment: again, I am quite new to django so please forgive my lack of proper terminology. What I mean by initiate is that inside my "base_right_panel.html" I initiate "base_categories.html" by using {% include "base_categories.html" %} to load my hardcoded version, as displayed above. Do I simply replace "base_categories.html" with the path to my app's "index.html" file?

Comment: You can do that if you like, or you could put the code that loops over the categories context variable directly into your `base_right_panel.html` template.  At least if that template is included in whatever template your view renders.

Comment: Which would be the right approach? The first seems more simplistic, but it sounds like the second is the right approach? To clarify, I am trying to replace the base_categories.html altogether which is what I believe you are suggesting. If so, would you mind posting an example of how I can loop over the categories from my app inside the base_right_panel.html as an answer so I can accept it if it works? I will edit my original question and add the base_right_panel.html code.

Comment: I'll add an answer later tonight - right now I am on my phone and typing it out wouldn't really work.  But the basic thing to remember is that a template is like a giant formatting string.  The various rendering functions slot the context you provide into the places your template says they should.  And more, but conceptually it's like a big "%s" interpolation.

Comment: @Alasdair: Getting back to the original question, is it possible to launch sql code directly in the html template without creating models or views? I have looked at that example but I am looking for a way to avoid creating unnecessary views/models, if it is indeed possible?

Comment: You can't write SQL directly in the template. As I've said before, you could create a custom template tag.

Answer (score 5):

This answer is not meant to disagree with Alasdair's - it's just to add some more information on working with templates.

The core handler of an HTTP request to a Django application is the view.  The view receives the HTTP request, as well as any arguments captured from the URL, and is responsible for returning an `HttpResponse` instance (or an instance of one of its subclasses) which will be returned to the browser.

The view is not bound to use any particular method to create the `HttpResponse`.  Rendering a template to include information derived from the database and from request information or URL arguments is sufficiently common that there's code to support it, like the `render` shortcut or its mostly obsolete antecedent `render_to_response`, but this is by no means required.  It's perfectly legitimate to have a view directly construct the `HttpResponse`:

```
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse('This is an index page.')
```

Or, for very simple HTML:

```
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse('<html><head><title>example</title></head><body>This is an index page.</body></html>')
```

In practice, I have often created `HttpResponse` instances directly to return json data or a dynamically created PDF or Excel file.

A simple way to slot information retrieved from the database into your response would be to use Python's built-in string interpolation:

```
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse('Hello, %s' % request.user.email)
```

Or you could use the advanced string formatting options:

```
def index(request):
    user_names = {}
    user_names['first_name'] = request.user.first_name
    user_names['last_name'] = request.user.last_name
    return HttpResponse('Hello, %(first_name)s %(last_name)s' % user_names)
```

All this is building up to the point that it doesn't matter how you generate the text contents of your `HttpResponse`.  All that matters is that you return one.

The template system is a powerful and extensible tool for generating text content, but that's all it does.  If you look at the [template docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#rendering-a-context) about rendering a template, you'll see some examples that are almost exactly the same as the the string interpolation above.

`render_to_response` was a shortcut that would accept a template and a context and return an `HttpResponse` with the rendered contents of that template and context.  Skipping over its `context_instance` and `content_type` parameters for the sake of demonstration, these two code blocks are identical in effect:

```
def index(request):
    t = Template('Hello, {{ first_name }} {{ last_name }}')
    c = Context({'first_name': request.user.first_name, 'last_name': request.user.last_name})
    response_text = t.render(c)
    return HttpResponse(response_text)
```

Assume a template `index.txt` exists as defined below, at the top level of an entry in the setting's [`TEMPLATE_DIRS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#the-template-dirs-setting) tuple.

```
index.txt
Hello, {{ first_name}} {{ last_name}}
```

Then the view above could be replaced with:

```
def index(request):
    t = get_template('index.html')
    c = Context({'first_name': request.user.first_name, 'last_name': request.user.last_name})
    response_text = t.render(c)
    return HttpResponse(response_text)
```

Alternatively, you can skip the explicit creation of the context object and rendering of the template into a string thus:

```
def index(request):
    return render_to_response('index.html', {'first_name': request.user.first_name, 'last_name': request.user.last_name})
```

On more recent versions of Django you should generally use the `render` shortcut rather than `render_to_response` - the details are a bit too much to go into if you're still struggling with getting context into your templates.

```
def index(request):
    return render('index.html', {'first_name': request.user.first_name, 'last_name': request.user.last_name})
```

Of course, part of what makes templates useful is that the rendering engine can perform certain kinds of logic and lookup.  I don't actually need to explictly keep looking up `first_name` and `last_name` - I can just pass in `request` as part of my context and look up its attributes in the templates:

```
index_showing_context.html
Hello, {{ request.user.first_name }} {{ request.user.last_name }}

def index_showing_context(request):
    return render('index_showing_context.html', {'request': request})
```

Even passing in `request` isn't strictly necessary in that example, because one of the differences between `render` and `render_to_response` that I alluded to above is that `request` is always part of the context for `render`.  But, again, that's an advanced subject.

So for your particular problem, it really doesn't matter where in your templates you render the data you want, as long as you have provided it to your view's context and are rendering the correct template.  The template is in effect just a file name used to find and build a string, into which your context will be interpolated.

The `{% include %}` template tag is one way to mix template fragments into other templates.  If I wanted to, I could set mine up like this:

```
header.html:
<head>
<title>This is a sample title.</title>
</head>

index.html:
<html>
{% include "header.html" %}
<body><p>This is my template body, {{ request.user.first_name }} {{ request.user.last_name }}.</p></body>
</html>

detail.html:
<html>
{% include "header.html" %}
<body><p>This is a detail page, probably for something selected in the context and given the context key 'object'.</p>
      <p>{{ object }}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

That works fine, but it's not the only option.  From your question, I see that you're using blocks and template inheritance.  A common idiom is to define a base template that all or almost all other templates will inherit from:

```
base.html
<html>
<head>
<title>{% block title %}Default title{% endblock %}</title>
{% block extra_head_elements %}{% endblock %}
</title>
<body>
{% block body_header %}Standard page header here {% endblock %}
{% block body_content %}{% endblock %}
{% block body_footer %}Standard page footer here {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>

index.html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}index {% endblock %}
{% block body_content %}<p>This is my template body, {{ request.user.first_name }} {{ request.user.last_name }}.</p>{% endblock %}

detail.html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}detail{% endblock %}
{% block body_content %}<p>This is a detail page, probably for something selected in the context and given the context key 'object'.</p>
      <p>{{ object }}</p>
{% endblock %}
```

So ultimately, I am not quite sure how you should best stitch together your right panel concept because it depends on the way you want your pages to work.  If it's going to be present everywhere or almost everywhere, I would recommend putting it into a base template that the rest of your templates will extend.  If you want it on exactly one page, just literally include it in that template.  If you want it on some but not all pages, a template fragment that you can `{% include %}` is probably best.

The main thing is to understand how the template engine will compose your `{% include %}` and `{% extends %}` tags, and to provide the necessary data to the template's context in your view.

Edit:
If I wanted to have a view and template pair that just retrieved the categories, this is a simple way to lay it out using your example model code and rendering.  There are other options.

```
index.html
<html>
<head><title>Simple category listing</title></head>
<body><p>The categories are:</p>
      <ul>
        {% for category in categories %}
          <li><a href="{{ category.base_url }}" id="nav_font">{{ category.name }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
</body>
</html>

view:
def index(request):
    categories = categoryList.objects.all()
    extra_context = {"categories": categories}
    return render_to_response("index.html", extra_context)
```

If I wanted to reuse the category listing on multiple pages, that gets back into the `include` vs. `extends` discussion above.  Either way, the template will always require your view to pass in `categories` as a context variable.

Comment: Looks like I have some reading :P Just to clarify, can I assume that user=table name & first_name=column name in "request.user.first_name"? so in my example I would use something like "request.mysite_categorylist.name" to access the data from the name column in my table?

Comment: `user` is a model instance representing a table - I worked with the `django.contrib.auth` user model in this example (documented here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/).  Models generally map to a specific table in the db, but if you let Django create your tables via `syncdb` it will prepend the app name - so this table would be `auth_user`.  You can override that for preexisting tables with the `db_table` attribute on the model's `Meta` class if necessary.  Your example view code looks right - match the `categories` key in your `extra_context` dict in the template.

Comment: And, yes, `first_name` is a model field.  Model fields are a subset of the database columns - if Django creates your tables, they'll line up exactly, but it's fine to not declare a model field for a column on a preexisting table if you don't need it.  And, again, there's an setting if you want a different field name from the column name.  Also, it's a special case that you get the current user from the `request` object - in your example you would use something like `categories = categoryList.objects.all()` to fetch the possible categories.  Then as you have, `extra_context={'categories': ...}

Comment: please see my modified base_categories.html file above. When using the new file, it shows my db is returning 0 results, which I know is false as there are +40 entries in the table. If my examples appear to be correct, any idea why the data is not being pulled? I created the table before creating the app, if that helps.

Comment: There are a couple of things to check.  Is your model class accurately mapped to your table?  I would usually check this using `python manage.py shell` to start an interpreter in the Django environment, then execute `categoryList.objects.count()`.  Is your template getting the right context?  That is a little harder to test, but you can (for debugging) just display `{{ categories }}` and set the variable `TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID` in your `settings.py` to something other than empty string to see if `categories` is in your context or not.

Comment: I tried your suggestion with manage.py shell but when I execute the line categoryList.objects.count() I get "NameError: name 'categoryList' is not defined". in light of your suggestion to ensure the table is correctly mapped, I added the argument "db_column=" to the Fields like so: name = models.CharField(max_length=255L, unique=True, db_column='name')

Even after explicitly setting the columns, it still gives me a count of 0?

Comment: When I set TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID to "Template Invalid!", it appears to replace the 0 with invalid string so I guess the error is happening before the sql?

Comment: In the shell, you need to import your model class first.  `from myapp.models import categoryList`.  Setting the `db_column` attribute isn't necessary unless you want your field names to differ from the database column names.

Comment: yeah, I kind of figured that out a bit after posting, feel a bit silly for asking lol. the results I get for the count is 44, which is the correct count for my category rows. It seems to me that there is a problem with how the variable "extra_context" is passed to the "index.html" file. The data is set correctly, I have looped through to check, but it seems to be empty when accessed through index.html.

Comment: from the shell I did:

import Categories.views.categoryList
categoryList("").__dict__["container"][0]

and the results are (trimmed):

'\r\n\r\n<div class="section" style="float: right;">\r\n  <h4 class="gradient">Category List</h4>\r\n  \r\n    <ul>\r\n      \r\n        <li><a href="" id="nav_font">911</a></li>\r\n      \r\n    </ul>\r\n  \r\n</div>

so it appears the template is created properly, but is not displayed? Any ideas?

Comment: Good thing to try.  Check your urls.py - if you're getting the wrong HTML back, you might be hitting the wrong view.

Comment: I think this might be where I am having the problem. I recreated the project last night to refresh and remove unnecessary modules, and I have made some major changes to the views and urls.py (Edit 4).

If I point my browser to localhost:8000/categories, the app works and the text appears on the right side of the screen as expected, although it is not formatted like it should be in the template. When I add {% include "categorylist.html" %} I get the category template formatting, but with the error instead of the category names. if I change the include to "categories/", it says it doesn't exist?

Comment: You need to add the category queryset to your context in your `HomeView`.  Remember, the view uses the templates to build the response - including a template that you also use in a different view (`IndexView`) does not cause any interaction with `IndexView`.

Comment: I'm not sure if I get you, are you saying that the IndexView class needs to be moved into the HomeView views.py? Or is there a different way to reference it from HomeView? Again, I am very new to Django so I apologize for needing the "For Dummies" explanation. :P Also please see my comments to the question as I opened a second question which is more relevant towards our comments here. As helpful as your comments and examples have been, this does stray from the original question.