# How to embed the results of my django app inside a template using something like {% include "app" %}?

Tags: python, django, templates, view

So far I have been able to Create a project and setup a Homepage. So far I have had success with styling the page and getting my nav areas setup. I have also created an app that pulls a list of category names from my database and displays it in a right-justified list. When I point my browser to the app url, it works perfectly, but when I try to include the view in my project it displays the base panel with an error, and the dictionary I passed to the view does not appear to be available.

This is what I get when I load the home url localhost:8000/ in my browser:

[image: url: localhost:8000/]

This is what I get when I load the app url localhost:8000/categories/ in my browser:

[image: url: localhost:8000/categories/]

Why am I not able to push the results of my app into my template? Both appear to work but not together?

**base_right_panel.html**

```
{% block content %}
  <div style="float: right;">
    <div id="base_categories" style="margin: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px;">
      {% block base_categories %}
        {% include "base_categories.html" %}
      {% endblock %}
    </div>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

**base_categories.html**

```
{% block content %}
  <div class="section" style="float: right;">
    <h4 class="gradient">Category List</h4>
    <ul>
      {% if categories %}
        {% for category in categories %}
          <li><a href="" id="nav_font">{{ category.title }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
      {% else %}
        <p>no data! {{ categories|length }}</p>
      {% endif %}
    </ul>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

**CategoryList/views.py**

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from CategoryList.models import CategorylistCategorylist #<-- Changed to match inspectdb result

class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name="base_categories.html" #<-- Changed name from index.html for clarity

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["categories"] = CategorylistCategorylist.objects.all()
        return context
```

**CategoryList/models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class CategorylistCategorylist(models.Model): #<-- Changed to match inspectdb
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255L, unique=True)
    base_url = models.CharField(max_length=255L, unique=True)
    thumb = models.ImageField(upload_to="dummy", blank=True) #<-- Ignored inspectdb's suggestion for CharField

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    # Re-added Meta to match inspectdb
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'categorylist_categorylist'
```

**CategoryList/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from CategoryList import views

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='base_categories'),
)

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
        {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
    url(r'', include('django.contrib.staticfiles.urls')),
) + urlpatterns
```

**MySite/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from home import views as home_view
from CategoryList import views as index_view

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', home_view.HomeView.as_view(), name="home"),

    url(r'^categories/$', index_view.IndexView.as_view(), name='base_categories'),#include('CategoryList.urls')),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    #url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
)

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
        {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
    url(r'', include('django.contrib.staticfiles.urls')),
) + urlpatterns
```

I have another open question which has the relevant code examples but the question differs from what I am asking here.

*[Is there a simple way to display mysql data in Django template without creating an app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17711985/is-there-a-simple-way-to-display-mysql-data-in-django-template-without-creating)*

Comment: edited 30 mins ago
Bill the Lizard -- Curious...what was edited?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the category queryset to your context in your `HomeView`. Remember, the view uses the templates to build the response - including a template that you also use in a different view (`IndexView`) does not cause any interaction with `IndexView`.

`HomeView` produces its response by rendering a template.  If that template uses `{% include %}` tags to pull in pieces of other templates, those pieces will be rendered using the context established by `HomeView`.  Nothing you do in `IndexView` has any effect on `HomeView`, and vice versa.

Continuing to reason by analogy to string interpolation, pretend your templates are global string variables instead of files on disk.  Your situation is something like this:

```
base_categories = "My categories are: %(categories)s."
base_right_panel = "This is the right panel.  Here are other fields before categories."
```

Using the {% include %} tag is something like string concatenation:

```
base_right_panel = base_right_panel + base_categories
```

Then your two views are analogous to this:

```
def home_view(request):
    context = {}
    return base_right_panel % context

def index_view(request)
    context = {'categories': ['a', 'b', 'c']}
    return base_categories % context
```

Unless you add the `categories` queryset to the context in `HomeView`, it will not be available to the template engine when rendering the response.

Your `HomeView` class should include the `get_context_data` method that you currently have in your `IndexView`.  I am not sure you actually need `IndexView` at all, unless you want to have something that serves that page with just the categories list.

Comment: Well explained, and this solved the problem in seconds, ty! :)

So basically because I added the categories within the app, and the HomeView was loaded first, the data never made it to HomeView before rendering the page?

Comment: Something like that.  `HomeView` is what creates the response - it receives a request object and has to return an `HttpResponse` instance.  A template is one tool views can use to do this, but they're not in any special or bound to URLs.  It would also be legit to return, say, `HttpResponse("Hello!")`.  Class-based views may be a little too abstract for a beginner - I think you might find it clarifying to work a little with function based views instead.